# TinyMCE: Uncaught TypeError: fileBrowserCallback is not a function

Tags: javascript, django, tinymce

I trying to use django-tinymce-filebrowser in my Django project. But I get some error from my minified TinyMCE JS file. I have no knowledge of JavaScript so I need help understanding this error and fix it.

**This is the traceback from Chrome:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: fileBrowserCallback is not a function
```

From the file:

```js
init: function(settings) {
   var self = this, editor = tinymce.activeEditor, editorSettings = editor.settings;
   var actionCallback, fileBrowserCallback, fileBrowserCallbackTypes;

   settings.spellcheck = false;

   fileBrowserCallbackTypes = editorSettings.file_picker_types || editorSettings.file_browser_callback_types;
   if (fileBrowserCallbackTypes) {
    fileBrowserCallbackTypes = Tools.makeMap(fileBrowserCallbackTypes, /[, ]/);
   }

   if (!fileBrowserCallbackTypes || fileBrowserCallbackTypes[settings.filetype]) {
    fileBrowserCallback = editorSettings.file_picker_callback;
    if (fileBrowserCallback && (!fileBrowserCallbackTypes || fileBrowserCallbackTypes[settings.filetype])) {
     actionCallback = function() {
      var meta = self.fire('beforecall').meta;

      meta = Tools.extend({filetype: settings.filetype}, meta);

      // file_picker_callback(callback, currentValue, metaData)
      fileBrowserCallback.call(
       editor,
       function(value, meta) {
        self.value(value).fire('change', {meta: meta});
       },
       self.value(),
       meta
      );
     };
    } else {
     // Legacy callback: file_picker_callback(id, currentValue, filetype, window)
     fileBrowserCallback = editorSettings.file_browser_callback;
     if (fileBrowserCallback && (!fileBrowserCallbackTypes || fileBrowserCallbackTypes[settings.filetype])) {
      actionCallback = function() {
       fileBrowserCallback(
        self.getEl('inp').id,
        self.value(),
        settings.filetype,
        window
       );
      };
     }
    }
   }

   if (actionCallback) {
    settings.icon = 'browse';
    settings.onaction = actionCallback;
   }

   self._super(settings);
  }
 });
});
```

I can't press the upload button at all. It doesn't trigger anything at all.

I'm using TinyMCE 4.3.2.

Comment: It would be helpful, If you could add bit of your code where you get this error

Comment: @pas7 Added now from the file.